# Python 3.6 USZIPCODE Install

Tags: anaconda, python-3.6

I'm brand new to Python. I've been using Python through Anaconda. I'm running Python 3.6.5. Right now, I'm trying to install a package called USZIPCODE from https://pypi.org/project/zipcodes/. I downloaded the zip file from this site in to my downloads folder. I then tried to use $ pip install uszipcode from the CMD prompt. This doesn't work. "Invalid Syntax" is returned. I've looked at videos on how to use pip to install other packages but they have not been able to solve my problem. The picture below should give some insight in to the issue. Any pointers on how I can install this package into python? Thank you!  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDJAI.png)

Comment: Are you running the command prompt as an administrator? I was able to succesfuly install the module with a: 'sudo pip install zipcodes' command on my linux box. So, try opening the command prompt as an administrator and typing: pip install zipcodes. If that doesn't work then let me know.

Comment: Unforunately that did not work. I tried both "sudo pip install uszipcodes" and "pip install uszipcodes" but neither worked. Do i need to tell the CMD prompt where the zip file is located in order for it to be extracted?

Comment: The zip file? Why do you have a zip file?  Are you trying to download the zipcodes module that you linked to or...?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no such module: uszipcodes. The module you provided a link to is called: zipcodes. The only downloads available via the link you provided are for the zipcodes module. If (for some strange reason) you wanted to get the module via a zip or tar you could use those downloads then unzip or unpack them and add them to your modules folder. However, if you just want the module then its simple: sudo pip install zipcodes.

Answer (score 1):

2 years too late to help bbranham, but for other Anaconda Python beginners having trouble using `pip install`, use the "Anaconda Powershell Prompt". For instance, on Windows 7:

1. Hit the windows key and type "Anaconda Powershell Prompt" and select in the search bar to open the Anaconda Powershell cmd prompt.
2. If you are using different environments make sure to activate your environment with `conda activate yourenvname`
3. `pip install uszipcode` should work out then (to download and install the uszipcode package to your active anaconda environment).